# Multiple marker Click event in android maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have some markers in my google map activity representing some shop locations. I need to write click event for each marker so i can open the corresponding site for each shop. I am using the following code to add markers.

```
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < shop.size() ; i++ ) {

        createMarker(shop.get(i).getLat(), shop.get(i).getLon(), shop.get(i).getShopname(),"", R.drawable.ic_location_city);
    }

  mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(ShoppingPage.this);


}
protected Marker createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String title, String snippet, int iconResID) {
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 9f));

    myMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .title(title)
            .snippet(snippet)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_location_city_black_24dp)));
    return myMarker;

}
```

When i am trying to add click listener to the markers i can't add click listener to all of them.I could only add click event to the last added marker . But i need to make click event for every marker in the map. Please help me. This is my code for click event.

```
 public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    if (marker.equals(myMarker))
    {
        //handle click here
      Log.d("title",""+ marker.getTitle());
        Log.d("position",""+ marker.getPosition());
    }
    return  true;
}
```

Comment: You can add click event for each marker. What's your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to add click event for each marker. with my current code only last added marker give response to the click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

First make your app to implement GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener Then create a Marker array :

```
Marker[] marker = new Marker[20]; //change length of array according to you
```

then inside

```
onMapReady(){
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
for(int i = 0 ; i < shop.size() ; i++ ) {
        marker[i] = createMarker(shop.get(i).getLat(), shop.get(i).getLon(), shop.get(i).getShopname(),"", R.drawable.ic_location_city);
    }
```

then finally

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
   //you can get assests of the clicked marker
   return false;
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

In onMarkerClick(...), 
    "if (marker.equals(myMarker))"
means that onMarkerClick only does anything for myMarker.
myMarker references the last created marker, because it keeps getting overwritten whenever createMarker is called.
So the suggestion is to remove "if (marker.equals(myMarker))"

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    if (marker.equals(myMarker))
    {
        //handle click here
      Log.d("title",""+ marker.getTitle());
        Log.d("position",""+ marker.getPosition());
    }
    return  true;
}
```

It should be:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    
    return  true;
}
```

And `marker` variable indicates which marker was clicked. BTW your question is rather pointless, you could set breakpoint on first if to see you are wrong and response is there for all markers.

Also, I would prefer something like that:

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker ->
{
   /*Do what you need with clicked marker*/
   return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give every marker an `OnClickListener`

```
.setOnClickListener(getOnClickAction());
```

And than an OnClickListener that handles the clicks.

```
View.OnClickListener getOnClickAction(){
        return new View.OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View v){
              //Handle Click
              v.getTitle(position);
          }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically **setOnMarkerClickListner** detects which marker you clicked.

I have a method to identify which marker is clicked if you didn't set any title to the marker.

First, create a marker **Map** with marker object as key and marker name as value.

```
private Map<Marker, String> markerMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, add the desired marker to the **Map** object.

```
marker = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
markerMap.put(marker,gymDataHolder.getTitle());
```

After that, use **setOnMarkerClickListner**

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(context, markerMap.get(marker), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when adding markers to map You can set a tag to each marker as the shop like this

```
 marker= mGoogleMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                     .title(user.name)
                     .icon({Your shop icon})
        marker.tag=shop
```

then you can implement on marker click listeners

```
override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?): Boolean {
    if(p0?.tag==null) return false
    var shop=(p0?.tag) as Shop
      Toast.makeText(context,shop?.name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    return true
}
```